# Serverless Framework deploy through CircleCI

Tags: serverless-framework, circleci

I'm trying to integrate `serverless` to my `circleci` workflow.
I tried first adding both, `key` and `secret` to `AWS permissions`, but that did not work.
Then, I added `key` and `secret` to `Environment variables` and in my config file:

```
sudo npm install -g serverless
sls config credentials --provider aws --key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --secret $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
sls deploy -v
```

But I see the same error:

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
You are not currently logged in. Follow instructions in http://slss.io/run-in-cicd to setup env vars for authentication.
```

Anyone had this issue? I could not find an answer or hint online. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked Circleci  stopped supporting `AWS Permissions` as a configurable option in the settings page.

You need to set the credentials as environment variables for the projects. The credentials should be named exactly `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

that's all you need to do. you don't have to do any additional step. I tried this on my project and it worked.

Your deployment step should simply be

```
sls deploy
```

Comment: I'll check and let you know how I'm doing it in my circleci project

Comment: Thanks. Excuse my ignorance but this is new for me. I have the key and secret in my environment variables of circleci. And in my `.circleci/config.yml` after installing serverles I added ``` export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY``` Is this right? Still failing.

Comment: Syntax is correct . I will check my circleci config and let you know

Comment: I don't have AWS credentials on my circle.yml. it must be already available from circleci integration with AWS. Give me some time , I will tell you

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time :D

Comment: Looks like circleci has changed. I need to change my project as well . I will let you know

Comment: Can you try logging the credentials . `echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`

Comment: updated my answer . you don't have to do anything other than setting the credential as the environment variables for the project.

Comment: K Sorry for the late response. I did not see you answer. I am still receiving the same error: `
Serverless: You are not currently logged in. Follow instructions in http://slss.io/run-in-cicd to setup env vars for authentication.
 
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
 
  You are not currently logged in. Follow instructions in http://slss.io/run-in-cicd to setup env vars for authentication.`
If I go to that page, they ask for setting up a role in AWS and adding its ARN to the serverless profile, but I am locked there. Thanks

Comment: i have create a new project on circleci, 1. i tested without setting credentials as environment variables = FAILED , 2. i set the credentials as environment variables = Passed

Comment: which page are you talking about

Comment: the page you are talking about is a `CICD feature` serverless.com of offering. its nothing to do with serverless.

Comment: you need to set it in this screen https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/settings/

Comment: I have that.
In the project settings, under `Build Settings > Environment Variables` I have both, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` with their proper values.
Then, in the iml file of circldeci, Im trying the following
`serverless config credentials --provider aws --key ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} --secret ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} --profile serverless-profile`
`serverless deploy`

Still the same error.
I can log the env variables: echo ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
Result: ********************

Really curious about what could be happening. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i am saying , you just have to do `serverless deploy` . you do not have to mention secret or profile. setting the environment variables itself enough

Comment: just `serverless deploy`

Comment: becuause the serverless command will use those environment variables automatically

Comment: Thanks a lot. I removed everything and just kept `serverless deploy` however I am still receiving the same error: `Serverless: You are not currently logged in. Follow instructions in http://slss.io/run-in-cicd to setup env vars for authentication. 
Exited with code exit status 1`. It is turning me crazy :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204762/discussion-between-arun-k-and-peter).

Answer (score 2):

This likely only applies to those trying to use Serverless Enterprise with the monitoring & dashboards they have set up.  @wintvelt's answer wouldn't work for me because if i deleted the org variable, it would likely break the connection needed for Enterprise. So steps for my CircleCI setup:

1. In CircleCI, create a Context for each environment with the AWS Key ID and Secret as environment variables (putting them in a context is a nice to have, you could use other methods of making Circle inject environment variables into builds).
2. In your Serverless Framework dashboard, create a new access key which you will use in Circle.
3. Create a new environment variable SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY with the value from step 2.

I got this idea from reading how Seed.run has users integrate with Serverless. For more info read this link: https://seed.run/docs/integrating-with-serverless-enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up to the previous answer: I had exactly the same error.
I took the solution from the chat as a solution.

For me the fixes I applied:

1. In CircleCI project settings, under "AWS permissions" I added the AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access key
2. In CircleCI project settings, under "Environment variables", I also added the AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access key
3. From my serverless.yml file, I **deleted the line with org variable**

For me, 1. and 2. alone was not enough. I also had to remove the line from my yml file to make deployment via CircleCI work.

For those landing here with the same issue, hope this helps!

Comment: If you wanted to continue using the Serverless Dashboard, you can re-add the app and org variable, and then use the SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY solution as shared above

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Still new to servetjes. Will try your steps .