# Using CircleCi environment variables for aws access/secret keys

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, api, circleci

I created a simple API test to post a document. The endpoint needs to be authenticated using AWS access and secret key. Here's my API test code.

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostRequest(string requestUrl, dynamic json = null, byte[] file = null)
        {
            var credentials = new ImmutableCredentials(accessKey, secretKey, null);

            var url= url.SetQueryParams(json);
            var httpContent = new ByteArrayContent(file );

            var response = await client.PostAsync(
                postUrl,
                httpContent,
                regionName: regionName,
                serviceName: serviceName,
                credentials: credentials);

            return response;
        }
```

Currently these credentials are hard coded (not great, I know). With my CI pipeline, I'm using CircleCi and I have stored my AWS keys in the environment variable section. My question now is how can I access and implement these variables to my test code?

The idea on what I'm trying to do is that I don't want to hard code my AWS keys in source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use circleci, but I don't use dot.net.

I have added AWS credentials as environment variables for the circleci project. After that, I don't include the credentials part of my nodejs code. the `aws-sdk` for `nodejs` will use the environment variables to get the credentials. I believe the behaviour should be same for dot.net based applications as well.

Hope this helps.

Reference:
[Serverless Framework deploy through CircleCI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431650/serverless-framework-deploy-through-circleci/59431773#59431773)

Comment: This helped! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CircleCI context](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/contexts/) to store the AWS keys and then specify the context in the CircleCI config. It will prevent keeping them in code.